# How to import hyperlink URLs using IMPORT functions on Google Sheets?

Tags: url, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the table of the most recently received Gazettes into this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWOVi41MZ_IyXznj400lpOx9WS4PinSX7Jw4THQtXm0/edit#gid=398151438). I've used the following formula to do it:

`=query(IMPORTHTML("https://discover.sabinet.co.za/government_gazette_current_index", "table", 1), "Select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5")`

The problem is that when the data comes through, it excludes the urls which the titles are hyperlinked to. Is there any way that I can get the urls to pull through as well?

I've unsuccessfully tried to use an IMPORTXML formula to do it:

```
`=IMPORTXML("https://discover.sabinet.co.za/government_gazette_current_index","//tr/td[1]/a/@href")`
```

Comment: Could you please clarify visually what information you want to retrieve?

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to see the urls that the titles under "Notice Title" are hyperlinked to in a separate column (reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWOVi41MZ_IyXznj400lpOx9WS4PinSX7Jw4THQtXm0/edit#gid=398151438). So I would like to have urls in column E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly what you want ... try this : in A1 = url, in A2

```
=importxml(A1,"//@href[contains(.,'rgg_gnum')]")
```

and in B2

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,"https://discover.sabinet.co.za/"&A2:A))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11l2mDXV-hrcbZQmNf6Bs9AUgOCZg0r-Y0DVdZiacuB8/edit?usp=sharing